# string variable date to double in c#

Tags: asp.net

In the following code ,i need to convert **string** to **double**. But the code doesn't work.

string fdate="7/4/2013";
   double nextdate = Convert.ToDouble( fdate);

Comment: You sure you aren't wanting to convert to `DateTime` and not a `Double`?

Comment: the string is in date format how would that be converted to Double?

Comment: Maybe he's looking to get total Ticks??

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to show the required result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
 DateTime ddd=Convert.ToDateTime("7/4/2013");
 double dd = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToString(ddd.Month) + Convert.ToString(ddd.Day) + Convert.ToString(ddd.Year));
```

It will surely work

Comment: Watch out: month 11 and day 1 will get the same result as month 1 and day 11 ("1112013").

Comment: @ Hans Kesting If we converting to double from any string date format , will only get result like you said. Do you have any other ideas? If you know let me too. Tnx for notified this fault

Comment: if you use `ddd.ToString("MMddyyyy")` a day 1 will result in a "01", so you get "11012013" or "1112013". But maybe a "yyyyMMdd" format is better: that will sort as expected from a date.

Answer (score 2):

First convert date string you have to `date` using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) and use it to `Convert.ToDouble` or `DateTime.ToOADate` to convert it to double.

```
string fdate = "7/4/2013";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(fdate, "d/m/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double nextdate = date.ToOADate();
```